# copy text to clipboard from recyclerview android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, copy

Hey I'm trying to copy text from recyclerview items into the clipboard its works when I try to do this inside an activity but when I try the code inside the viewholder i get Unresolved reference: CLIPBOARD_SERVICE erorr here is the code:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val currentitem = userList[position]

    holder.username.text = currentitem.name
    holder.app.text = currentitem.app
    holder.password.text = currentitem.password

    holder.copy.setOnClickListener(){
        val clipboardManager = getSystemService(holder.itemView.context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager
        val clipData = ClipData.newPlainText("text", currentitem.password)
        clipboardManager.setPrimaryClip(clipData)
        Toast.makeText(holder.itemView.context, "Text copied to clipboard", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Change `holder.itemView.context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE` with `Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE` and Add `holder.itemView.context.getSystemService` instead of simple `getSystemService`

```
        val clipboardManager = holder.itemView.context.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager
        val clipData = ClipData.newPlainText("text", "1234567890")
        clipboardManager.setPrimaryClip(clipData)
        Toast.makeText(holder.itemView.context, "Text copied to clipboard", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```